# How long does it take a full text index to update after inserting a large amount of text?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-search

I'm trying to track down an issue where some searches do not return a hit but do return a hit after some time.

Process. We currently grab some 150,000 pages of text and insert them into our database. After, we then do a search on the text for some keywords. However it would seem that when we do an initial search the FT catalog doesn't find our keywords. But after rerunning the search the key words show up.

So what I'd like to know. How long of a lag is there between the time you do an insert on a table and the result populating in the full text catalog and showing up in a search?

Server Specs

Dual Xeon E5-2670 @2.6ghz

256 gb ram

ssd drives.

Comment: That would depend upon a lot of factors, such as the model you use for population (example you could have an incremental job that handles things, or automatic). It will also depends upon the performance characterisitcs of your server, including CPU and disk IO. Not to mention available memory for the crawl which lives outside the SQL memory space.

Comment: I've added the server specs. it's a very decent server. population is set to auto.    now sql server is using 209gb of ram. makes me wonder about that crawl.  would 40gb of ram not be enough?

Comment: How is the FT population setup?

Comment: default settings. change tracking is auto.

Comment: It's a background thread, so low priority, but I would expect to see things picked up within 120 seconds (depending on the volume and size of imports). I'd recommend you do some tests to see what values you generally see and set your expectation appropriately.

Comment: I'll bet this is the issue. we will need to put a pause in in the process to make sure the FTI is ready for searches.   thanks.